# Parrot rehab from leg amputation

Tags: training, birds, parrots, surgery

About a month ago, my Senegal parrot Tycho (~150g, 24 years old) started chewing on his leg, and wouldn't stop.  Without going into agonizing detail about this -- other than to say he's been in constant care of excellent avian specialists from the day this started -- the process unfortunately ended with a surgical leg amputation two days ago, as we just couldn't clear up the osteomyelitis.

Because he was in an e-collar (which is a heartbreaking thing to do to a bird) before the surgery, he's been in a smallish hospital cage with no perches, but with some sea grass mats for his comfort.

The good news is that the amputation seems to have done it's job.  He's perking up, and showing more of his old self every hour (and complaining more about taking his meds) -- and most importantly, he's not self-mutilating without an e-collar (knock on wood).  I'm leaving him in his hospital cage until he learns to deal with his mobility issues.  The question I have is if there's any advice on coaching him through his new situation. I was thinking a ladder in his hospital cage, mounted low so that it has a very gentle slope, might be a good device for him.

It would be great if I can get more suggestions about things that would help him rehab, as well as any heads-ups about what he's going to be going through.  I'd welcome any and all ideas from anyone, but if your recommendation come from actual experience, please try to highlight that so I can weight my decisions appropriately.

As a last request, any ideas to facilitate a modified "step up" would also be great.  With one foot, I think he's going to need to stabilize with his beak, and I just can't envision how this will work out.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! I never had a bird, so I have more questions than answers for this. But I am sure someone may have suggestions for you. I would imagine some kind of bar to the stairs, as humans have to use their hands. And also ladders to be higher than needed for the foot, instead high as the beak would arise while climbing it. Was there ever the option to give the parrot company? I have learned that they are very social minimum with some kind of "married" partner?

Comment: @Allerleirauh  extra rails for a beak grip is a great idea.  Solo parrots tend to make better pets than paired parrots, and often adopt their humans as part of their flock.  Their interactions with people really change when paired.  At this point, it's probably a bit dangerous to have him in contact with other birds.

Comment: I would love to hear how Tycho got on. My Blue Fronted Amazon Charli just had her leg amputated yesterday after a traumatic freak accident. I’m finding the whole process very daunting and quite lost myself accepting this is her reality. There’s little information available, and a lack of support groups for us to all share our experiences on. What cage modifications have you found work best? When did Tycho start to use their stump, if ever? Did Tycho adjust well? How did you modify a simple ‘step up’? My girl had learned so many tricks prior that she’ll likely never do again such as to wave, sh